# What's the Christadelphian take on eating blood products?

Tags: diet, christadelphians

I have a friend, a Jehovah's Witness, with whom I shared a childhood neighborhood and school up until junior high. I recall our school in Sweden sometimes serving dishes like blood pudding. In such instances, alternate meals were provided for him and also some Muslim classmates.

I asked him about this recently and he said that JWs refrain from consuming blood due to prohibitions found in the Bible, such as Genesis 9:4 and Acts 15:28-29. He said meat can normally contain traces of blood but if blood was drained after the animal was killed, they can eat the meat. They would not consume products were blood was explicitly added.

Here are the Bible scriptures, from King James Version

**[Genesis 9:3,4](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Genesis-Chapter-9/#3)**

> Every moving thing that liveth shall be meat for you; even as the
> green herb have I given you all things. But flesh with the life
> thereof, which is the blood thereof, shall ye not eat.

**[Acts 15:28,29](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Acts-Chapter-15/#28)**

> For it seemed good to the Holy Ghost, and to us, to lay upon you no
> greater burden than these necessary things; That ye abstain from meats
> offered to idols, and from blood, and from things strangled, and from
> fornication: from which if ye keep yourselves, ye shall do well. Fare
> ye well.

I noticed that Christadelphians share many of the same views as JWs so wanted to ask about their view.

What is the Christadelphian view on eating products containing blood?